# Как загрузить информацию с сервера без обновления страницы, аякса или вебсокетов?

Tags: php

Можно ли на простом хостинге без применения ajax запросов и обновления страницы подгружать в режиме реального времени обновленные данные, например, из базы данных в клиентскую часть?

Кому не сложно, можно пример?

Comment: Учитывая что AJAX это как раз название технологии получения данных без обновления страницы, то без него как бы никак. И в тегах у вас php, а это делается исключительно на клиенте. на php все как обычно, только отдаете не всю страницу а только нужные данные

Comment: с этими вебсокетами черт ногу сломит, гора кода, консоли, ничего толком не пойму, а задачка очень маленькая. просто подгружать юзерам изменения из базы по мере их обновления, но чтобы это не грузило сайт, чтобы постоянно не посылались запросы пачками от всех пользователей

Comment: в тегах у меня php, так как серверная часть php, возможно это нужно учитывать тоже. а что это на клиентской делается я понимаю

Comment: а AJAXом будет каждые 100мс отправляться запрос всеми пользователями с вопросом, "а есть ли там что-то новенькое?". это непосильная для меня нагрузка

Comment: https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1452 берете первый пример. вот он отправляет запрос на сервер и заменяет на странице блок с классом results на содержимое которое прислал сервер. Указанная в примере response.php должна собственно этот кусок сайта выдать

Comment: И да, это даст разовое обновление. разумеется этот код должен выполняться периодически. для этого использовать javascript setTimeout

Comment: спасибо, но я об этом знаю. это не подходит мне. выше описал почему. мне нужно что-то на подобии вебсокетов, но чтобы было легко реализовать на простом хостинге. вот не знаю, возможно ли такое

Comment: Как бы есть только 2 способа передачи данных: 1. обычный http, когда клиент шлет один запрос и получает один ответ. 2. Клиент подключается и ждет пока сервер не сообщит что произошло. Если вам не нравится первый вариант, то остается только второй и реализуется он либо через websocket, либо HTTP SSE. И да, на сервере будет много кода, Обеспечивающего работу постоянно подключенных клиентов. И да, этот отдельный сервис который "простой хостинг" может и не поддерживать. без вариантов

Comment: спасибо, он даже не то чтобы не нравится, он очень при очень жручий. должно же быть что-то простое(может быть есть какие-то подключаемые внешние решения

Comment: Хотя вот нашел вам простой пример для SSE. http://mpbox.ru/collect/js-plugins/overclock-site/server-sent-events.html там в конце php код приведен, отправляющий данные. главное что бы ваш простой хостинг не прибил по таймауту запущенный скрипт

Comment: Но надо понимать что вам важнее. Первый вариант это много подключился-получил ответ-отключился. А второй - это подключился и получаю данные. А раз вы работаете на php, да еще и на "простом хостинге", где php выполняется только под управлением web-сервера то второй вариант требует поддерживать запущенным экземпляр php с вашим кодом на каждое соединение, а это жрет память и при сотне постоянных коннектов ваш "простой хостер" очень обидеться, ибо память на серверах дорогой ресурс

Comment: Поэтому действительно эффективный метод - это отдельный сервис, постоянно запущенный в ОС, поддерживающий одновременно много соединений одним процессом. Но это выходит за пределы понятия "простой хостинг", так же как и за стандартный способ использования php

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

Аякс это и есть загрузка информации с сервера без обновления страницы.

Поскольку речь о "простом хостинге", то и решение тут подойдёт самое простое, по таймауту подтягивать данные с сервера раз в 5 секунд через setTimeout.

Comment: ratchet воспользовался. на хостинге обычном сделал чат)) выделили мне порт для сокетов. я по ssh зашел на сервер и с помощью tmux запустил вебсокет сервер, демонизировал его и все ок, работает. потом выделенный сервер приобрету.

Answer (score 0):

C php такое не прокатит. Нужно использовать другие языки, а веб-хостинги такое не любят. Как вариант, можно арендовать сервер и самому все настроить.